# A drop down menu for countries provinces/states

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a option select menu that allows users to select countries and provinces/states. I am using helper methods that contain arrays of all the countries and most of the provinces/states. I use the helper method in the form with option select to pre populate a drop down menu. The code is given below.

```
 <%= f.label :Country %>
 <%= f.select :country, options_for_select(country, "Canada")%>

 <%= f.label :State_or_Province %>
 <%= f.select :states, options_for_select(states, "Ontario") %>
```

The methods `country` and `states` are defined in the helper files. The code for both of them are given below.

```
module StatesHelper
  def states
  states_array = %w{
      Alabama               
      Alaska
      Arizona
      Arkansas
      California
      Colorado
      Connecticut
      Delaware
      .....
 }
    states_array.sort_by{ |e| e.downcase }
  end
end

module CountriesHelper
  def country
    country_array = [
      "Afghanistan",
      "Aland Islands",
      "Albania",
      "Algeria",
      "American Samoa",
      "Andorra",
      "Angola",
       ....
]
  country_array.sort_by{ |e| e.downcase }
  end
end
```

This is working perfectly fine. However, I wanted the dropdown for the states/provinces a little more dynamic. I wanted the API such that when a user clicks "Canada", the Canadian provinces show up and similarly when a user click "USA", the American states show up.

I made two more helper files with just the American states and Canadian provinces. In the scoreboard form, I tried an if/else statement. The code is given below.

```
<% if f.select :country, options_for_select(country, "Canada") %>
 <%= f.label :State_or_Province %>
 <%= f.select :states, options_for_select(canadian_provinces, "Ontario") %>
 <% end %>
```

The if and else statement is not correct. The methods `canadian_provinces` and `Canada` are both arrays. I want to write that, "**if Canada is selected from that array then show Canadian provinces**". I want to do the same thing with USA. I understand that if I save the data then I can use methods to compare. However, I am not sure how to do that in the form before the data is saved. I am pretty sure you have to do this on a client side, just not sure how or what the right tools are. As always, any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a simpler option would be to ask for a zip code and use Ziptastic’s API to fill in the rest.
https://css-tricks.com/using-ziptastic/

Comment: I am using rails and the Ziptastic gem isn't actively maintained. it's development state is inactive

Comment: Oh, bummer. That’s good to know, though, thanks for the heads up.